# Get a single field from multi-column ListView using SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, listactivity, simpleadapter

I have a ListActivity in which i have used a SimpleAdapter to create a list which has 2 fields. The pair of values are stored using a Map, and the list is an ArrayList. 
I have an onItemClickListener for this. On selecting a list entry, i get the pair i.e. the 2 values. I need to get only 1 of those values.

For example, if the list item is "John", "123" . I want to store "123" in a string after selecting the entry from the list
Any help?

Here's the code snippet:

```
        ListView lv = getListView();
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        list.add(putData(scanned_name, scanned_addr));

        String[] from = { "name", "address" };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) { 


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch the content of `android.R.id.text1` or `android.R.id.text2`. So, in your `onItemClick(...)` you have to do:

> TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
>   TextView v1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
>   String content1=v.getText().toString();
>   String content2=v2.getText().toString();

and you can manage them as you want, even within a Toast:

> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),v.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Thanks. Worked nicely.
Just that since i used the predefined layout simple_list_item_2, it should be 
        `TextView v = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
         TextView v1 = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);`